# WebApi does not accept post (404 error)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC4 web project with WebAPI enabled.

I want to post data to the API controller but the post is not working, I am getting a 404 every time (breakpoint inside the Add method is not hit)....

Here is the code:

```
public class IncidentSessionLogController : ApiController
{
   [HttpPost]
   public void Add(MyInputDTO inputData)
   {
   }
}
```

I use action based routing:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "ControllerAndAction",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}");

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "ControllerAndActionAndId",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}
```

I use Fiddler to post the data:

```
http://localhost:42901/api/IncidentSessionLog/Add
```

My site is hosted in IIS express for development currently, I add the JSON object literal in the request body in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, thanks to my collegue !

The MVC routing(which I forgot to post originally), was interfering with the API routing, so I have to add a constraint to the MVC routing :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Game", action = "Start", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { controller = @"^((?!(api)).)*$" });
```

Comment: Yes, that would do it :). You could also just choose to register the WebAPI routes before the MVC route. Then, you wouldn't even need a constraint since routes are matched using their order.